# Changing shapefile (.shp) format to Object File Format (.off) file?

Tags: shapefile, shp2pgsql

I got a map and its format is .shp. What tool can be used to change it to one of the following file formats .off, .ply, .wrl, .obj, .m, .gim. ？

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please edit the question to contain the name of the software that uses that format. Also, be careful to distinguish between *data* and *maps*. Shapefile is a data transfer standard.

Answer (score 2):

Since i don't know wich GIS system you are using, i can't tell you if there is a spectific tool to change the format of your files.

However, you could use an online converter such as :
http://conversionai.com/file/3-d-slash-cad/shp-shapes-file/obj-lightwave-3-d-object

I cannot tell for the other file extension, but i know it can change the format of your .SHP to .OBJ.